# Boost Python: polymorphic container?

Tags: c++, python, boost, polymorphism, boost-python

I have a method (or function) which returns a reference to a list of polymorphic objects:

```
class A {

};
class B : public A {

};


std::list<boost::shared_ptr<A> >& getList();
```

How do I expose such a function in boost::python so that when iterating on the list in python, I would see the different types of `A`s and `B`s ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure your classes are indeed polymorphic (i.e. they have at least one virtual function or a virtual destructor).  Your example above doesn't, though I'm sure your real use case does.  Without that none of Boost.Python's RTTI-based machinery for polymorphism will work.

Then, if you've exposed both classes with Boost.Python and registered `shared_ptr` converters for them:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example) {
    bp::class_<A >("A");
    bp::register_ptr_to_python< boost::shared_ptr<A> >();
    bp::class_< B, bp::bases<A> >("B");
    bp::register_ptr_to_python< boost::shared_ptr<B> >();
}
```

...that's all you need to do to make sure Python only ever sees the most-derived type.  There's no need to do anything special to ensure `A` is casted to `B` when possible.

That still leaves the question of how to wrap a function that returns a container.  The simplest is probably to use the indexing suite included with Boost.Python:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/v2/indexing.html

There are other options floating around the web (including a "version 2" of the indexing suite that is better in many respects, but isn't included with Boost.Python), but for simple problems this is probably the most convenient.

Comment: indeed, a virtual d'tor was what I had missing.

Comment: Regarding the question of how to wrap a function that returns a container:
This method also works straightforward with exposing methods returning a boost::python::list.
I.e. by appending boost::shared_ptr to polymorphic python elements to the list. Dereferencing the pointers when accessing the list at runtime will then be implicitly done as described (if said register_ptr_to_python<> definitions do exist).