# boost python failed to recognize multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, boost-python

I have multiple inheritance of c++ classes as follow:

```
struct RefCounterBase
{
    virtual ~RefCounterBase(){}
 ....
};
struct A : public virtual RefCounterBase{
    virtual void method_a(){...}
};
struct B : public virtual RefCounterBase{
    virtual void method_b(){...}
};
class Concrete : public A, public B{
    virtual void method_concrete(){...}
};
```

And some smart pointer based on inheritance of `RefCounterBase`

```
template <class T>
struct SmartPtr{
 ...
}
```

Following code describe declaration of Concrete in python in boost 1.55

```
boost::python::class_<
     Concrete, 
     boost::python::bases<A,B>,
     SmartPtr<Concrete>, 
     boost::noncopyable>("Concrete", "some doc", boost::python::no_init)
    .def("method_concrete", &Concrete::method_concrete, "Some doc")
```

At last I have some factory that return instance of `A`. In python code I made a check that instance is `B` and need invoke `method_b`. I get an error as follow:

```
'A' object has no attribute 'method_b'
```

Looks my problem is near the same as described there [Boost Python: polymorphic container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579739/boost-python-polymorphic-container) but I cannot fix it in proposed way.

**UPDATE**: I've added diagnostic print to figure out what is returned from my factory - the type of result is `A`, and

```
type(a_inst).mro()
```

returns `[<class 'A'>, <class 'Boost.Python.instance'>, <class 'object'>]` - what means that boost doesn't resolve correct information at compile time

Comment: Any chance for a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  With what is currently presented, it is not clear to me as to why one would expect an object with a C++ runtime type of `A` to have `method_b()`.